# How to make an option in select box readonly not disabled using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to make an option in select box readonly not disabled  using jquery? I have a multiple select box for selecting roles and a single select primary role.

Now i want to make the selected option in primary role to automatically checked in roles multiple select box in read only  mode.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you post your html/scripts you have at this point? Or better even, could you create a fiddle at http://jsFiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this)
        .siblings('select')
        .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
        .attr('disabled', true)
        .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```